# kivy: FloatLayout widget doesn't update its position/size when i resize the window

Tags: layout, resize, widget, window, kivy

In my exercise, the widget "TextInput" doesn't update its position and its size, when i resize the window; instead the widget "Label" updates correctly its size and its position. Why? Can someone help me, please?

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle



class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args)



        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(255, 255, 255, 1) 
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

        def update_rect(instance, value):
            instance.rect.pos = instance.pos
            instance.rect.size = instance.size


        self.bind(pos=update_rect, size=update_rect)



        self.add_widget(TextInput(text='InsertText', multiline=False, size_hint=(1, 0.04),
                                  pos_hint={'right': 1, 'y': 0.879}, font_size='12sp'))

        self.add_widget(Label(text='label example', color=(0,0,255,0.5), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}))






class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Your example works for me, try to put in pos_hint=('right':1, 'top':0.879), size_hint=(1, 0.1) to see a bigger difference

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I replace 'y' with 'top' and this fact solves other problems! I thought it was the same thing, so i can't understand why it is so different now.... Anyway the widget TextInput doesn't stop moving itself, when i resize the window :(

Comment: y is the lowest point of the widget on the *Y axes*. you should post a another question about your other problem with an example